# flutter_tts error: Invalid argument: Instance of 'SpeechSynthesisEvent'

Tags: flutter, text-to-speech, flutter-web

I am trying to call flutter_tts after a page has finished building:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    WidgetsBinding.instance.addPostFrameCallback((_) {
      _speak('testing');
    });
  }
```

However, I obtained this error:

Invalid argument: Instance of 'SpeechSynthesisEvent'

Flutter_tts is working perfectly if called within an onPressed().

Could anyone help?

Answer (score 1):

I found the problem. It was due to the Autoplay Policy of Google:

https://developers.google.com/web/updates/2017/09/autoplay-policy-changes

As there is no user interaction just after the page has been built, Chrome prohibited the playing of sound.